# How do I copy a file from an internal server to an FTP server using command shell?

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp

I'm reading this site:

http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm

But it's confusing and I'm not sure how to structure the command.

Basically I have a few text files I need to COPY from SERVER1 (internal server) to an FTP server (outside the company). Let's call the ftp location "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Folder1"

Let's just use one file for this, called test.txt

The username and password for the FTP is u: bob p: bob123

How would I construct a copy command to this FTP that uses a username/password?

**Source file location: C:\test.txt**

**Destination location: ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Folder1**

**Username: bob**

**Password: bob123**

This is part of an automated process so there's no human intervention.

```
ftp ...
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the commands below to a script to get the functionality that you want.  If you plan on scripting this I would recommend using variables for destination, filenames etc.

```
ftp <destination location> user <username> <password>
put <local filename> <filename on destination server>
bye
```

If you need to copy multiple files you can use `mput -i` as long as you can represent all the local files that need to be copied using an expression, for example, '*.c', to copy all c files.